# Can't push to bitbucket from eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket, eclipse-neon

When I'm trying to commit and push a rep in `bitbucket` from `Eclipse Neon` I get this message:

[image]

When I push using command line it works perfectly!

I tried to go to:

```
eclipse/myeclipse > menu
window > preferences > general > security >
content > click "delete" > ok
```

and then I re-entered my credentials bu the problem still remains.

It's worth to mention that when I tried to `Synchronize workspace` I got the message `No changes found.`

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000#c24).

Just go to `Help->Install New Software...` and write to `Work with` this url: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.5.1a

Then select `EPP Marketplace Client` and install it. Restart `Eclipse Neon` and now push mechanism will work properly.